# How do I develop on a Samsung Vibrant using Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android game using Windows 7 64 bit. My Android device is a Samsung Vibrant running version 2.1.

I installed the USB driver software on my machine using SDK Setup. The phone has USB debugging turned on.

When I plug in the phone, Windows automatically searches and fails to locate the driver.

I go to device manager and find the phone > update drivers and navigate to the usb driver folder in the sdk directory. Windows does not find the driver.

Solutions please?

Answer (score 1):

For some devices you need to download the drivers from the device manufacturer. For example the motorola milestone and some devices from Alcatel aren´t represented in the sdk usb driver folder either. Just check on the Samsung site if they have the right drivers available.